# .one("click", function () not working without any issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, oneclick

My `.one("click", function ()` not working properly I mean fast one is working or execute, but second one not execute, i'm confused, why not working? 
2 days ago it's was working fine, but today not working without any changes or issue, there are no error on console log.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //Fast one Working
  $(".recent-post-title-block span, .more-recent-button").one("click", function () {  //Working
    $("#Blog1").addClass("loading"),
      $(".date-outer").addClass("more-date-outer").fadeTo("500", 0),

  }),
  //Second one Not Working
    $(".sly-scroll-title3 .title-padding, .more-bottom-label-post").one("click", function () {   //Not Working
    $(".list-label-widget-content").addClass("loading"),
      $(".bottom-label-post-main li").addClass("show-more-post").fadeTo("500", 0),

  });

});
```

Please any suggestion?

Comment: Can you add your html and css?

Comment: Exactly, please add html and css. My guess would be that class you use for binding changed - one or more, or maybe the order of the classes was changed.

Comment: The issue is that you're using `,` to end all of your lines, instead of `;`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change commas to semicolons at the end of the lines, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Fast one
    $(".recent-post-title-block span, .more-recent-button").one("click", function() {
        $("#Blog1").addClass("loading");
        $(".date-outer").addClass("more-date-outer").fadeTo("500", 0);
    });

    //Second one
    $(".sly-scroll-title3 .title-padding, .more-bottom-label-post").one("click", function() {
        $(".list-label-widget-content").addClass("loading");
        $(".bottom-label-post-main li").addClass("show-more-post").fadeTo("500", 0);
    });
});
```

If you you need these events to fire more than once (i.e. if user clicks on these elements again later on) then also change `.one` to `.on`.

Comment: `.one` is a perfectly legitimate JQuery function, it fires the bound event only *once* before disposing of it.

Comment: "Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type."

Comment: I just assumed that it's preferred to fire these events every time and not just once. Otherwise, of course, you only need to replace commas with semicolons.

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly.